# Pairing the weight of a protein sequence with the correct sequence

Tags: for-loop, biopython

This piece of code is part of a larger function. I already created a list of molecular weights and I also defined a list of all the fragments in my data.
I'm trying to figure out how I can go through the list of fragments, calculate their molecular weight and check if it matches the number in the other list. If it matches, the sequence is appended into an empty list.

```
combs = [397.47, 2267.58, 475.63, 647.68]
fragments = ['SKEPFKTRIDKKPCDHNTEPYMSGGNY', 'KMITKARPGCMHQMGEY', 'AINV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'HMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'DHTAQPCRSWPMDYPLT', 'IEEATHM', 'MVGKMDMLEQYA', 'GWPDII', 'QIQDY', 'TPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYA', 'HGLRWVQIQDYAINV', 'KKKNARKW', 'TPCYELHGLRWV']
frags = []

for c in combs:
  for f in fragments:
    if c == SeqUtils.molecular_weight(f, 'protein', circular = True):
      frags.append(f)
print(frags)
```

I'm guessing I don't fully know how the SeqUtils.molecular_weight command works in Python, but if there is another way that would also be great.

Comment: What does your code do currently?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 It's not printing anything, but it also doesn't give me an error. Or is your question more about what the larger function does that this piece of code is a part of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing floating point values for equality. That is bound to fail. You always have to account for some degree of error when dealing with floating point values. In this particular case you also have to take into account the error margin of the input values.

So do not compare floats like this

```py
x == y
```

but instead like this

```py
abs(x - y) < epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is some carefully selected arbitrary number.

I did two slight modifications to your code: I swapped the order of the `f` and the `c` loop to be able to store the calculated value of `w`. And I append the value of `w` to the list `frags` as well in order to better understand what is happening.

Your modified code now looks like this:

```py
from Bio import SeqUtils

combs = [397.47, 2267.58, 475.63, 647.68]
fragments = ['SKEPFKTRIDKKPCDHNTEPYMSGGNY', 'KMITKARPGCMHQMGEY', 'AINV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV',
             'MQCL', 'HMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'DHTAQPCRSWPMDYPLT', 'IEEATHM', 'MVGKMDMLEQYA', 'GWPDII', 'QIQDY',
             'TPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYA', 'HGLRWVQIQDYAINV', 'KKKNARKW', 'TPCYELHGLRWV']

frags = []
threshold = 0.5
for f in fragments:
    w = SeqUtils.molecular_weight(f, 'protein', circular=True)
    for c in combs:
        if abs(c - w) < threshold:
            frags.append((f, w))
print(frags)
```

This prints the result

```
[('AINV', 397.46909999999997), ('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 2267.5843), ('MQCL', 475.6257), ('QIQDY', 647.6766)]
```

As you can see, the first value for the weight differs from the reference value by about 0.0009. That's why you did not catch it with your approach.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lydia van Dyke! This helps a lot, although I now get an error that goes like this: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'. I don't really know what the problem is at this point. Edit: I just checked and c is defined as a tuple, while it's clearly a list.

Comment: Above code runs fine on my machine. The unsupported operand happens when you integrate the code in your program?

Comment: I had to change something about how combs was iterated, but it works as intended now. Thanks for the help!